# How to run PostgreSQL functions with parameters passed from MS Access form?

Tags: postgresql, function, arguments, ms-access-2016

I want to run the function and pass the Arguments from MS Access Form.
The created table should then be used in a Report.
Better if the Table created is a PostgreSQL view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.emergency_leave_by_department(enteredyear integer,departmentno integer)

    RETURNS TABLE(id integer, dept_code character varying, dept_name character varying, emp_code character varying, first_name character varying, start_time timestamp without time zone, end_time timestamp without time zone, start_date date, end_date date, noofdays integer, category_id integer, category_name character varying) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT  
    public_personnel_department.id,
        public_personnel_department.dept_code,
        public_personnel_department.dept_name,
        public_personnel_employee.emp_code,
        public_personnel_employee.first_name,
       public_att_leave.start_time,
        public_att_leave.end_time,
       date(public_att_leave.start_time) AS start_date,
       date(public_att_leave.end_time) AS end_date,
       work_days(date_part('year'::text, public_att_leave.end_time)::integer, public_att_leave.start_time,               public_att_leave.end_time, public_personnel_department.dept_code::integer) AS noofdays,
    public_att_leave.category_id,
    public_att_leavecategory.category_name

   FROM public_personnel_department
     JOIN public_personnel_employee ON public_personnel_department.id = public_personnel_employee.department_id
     JOIN (public_att_leavecategory
     JOIN public_att_leave ON public_att_leavecategory.id = public_att_leave.category_id) ON public_personnel_employee.id = public_att_leave.employee_id

  WHERE (public_personnel_department.dept_code::text = departmentno ::text ) AND public_att_leave.category_id = 2 AND date_part('year'::text, public_att_leave.start_time) = enteredyear::double precision OR (public_personnel_department.dept_code::text = departmentno ::text ) AND public_att_leave.category_id = 2 AND date_part('year'::text, public_att_leave.end_time) = enteredyear ::double precision
  ORDER BY public_personnel_department.dept_code, public_personnel_employee.first_name;

END; 
$BODY$;
```

Can not pass arguments and run function from MS Access

Comment: 1) You are not actually creating a table, you returning a set of values in table form. Essentially you are making a temporary view over the data. In other words the data returned does not persist. 2) As to form do `select * from public.emergency_leave_by_department(<parameters>)`.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to call the function form MsAccess, Postgresql is on a remote server but I can link to Tables and views only

Comment: Use a [Pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42).

Comment: Thank You ,helped a lot I'm half way there I run the function from MsAccess Pass-through query Successfully , I still have trouble passing the arguments from the form to the query